# How to solve gradle build fail caused by org.apache.jasper.JasperException:xxx is quoted with ["] when upgrade tomact from v8.0.x to v 8.5.30

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, gradle-eclipse

When I upgrade Tomcat from v8.0.x to v8.5.30, Tomcat can run successful.

I run gradle build. The step convertToJavaFromJSP will be fail caused by org.apache.jasper.JasperException:xxx is quoted with ["] .

The custom task which is convertToJavaFromJSP in build.gradle like

```
task convertToJavaFromJSP(type:com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.TomcatJasper) {
    uriroot = file("${project.webAppDirName}")
    outputDir = file("${project.ext.precompileDir}")
    classpath = configurations.precompile + sourceSets.main.output
    javaEncoding = 'UTF-8' //encoding is required or the task will fail
    addWebXmlMappings = true
    webXmlFragment = file("${project.webAppDirName}/generated_web_app.xml")
}
```

In old tomact v8.0.x, `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false` in gradle.properties will solve this problem.

However tomact v8.5.30, STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING has been deprecated, what code can replace it?
Or maybe some oaramter set in build.gradle will be helpful?
Which paramter I should add in gradle.properties to let gradle build success?

Comment: Full stack trace?